Distinct count from multiple tables and slicers
To create a gap analysis, I want to create a customer-specific table or matrix, showing products for a given customer, and a second one showing all products available in that country.
We have the following tables:

Customers: Group Name, Parent Name, Company Name
Countries: Territory, Region, Country Name
Brands: Brand Group, Brand Name
Products: Brand Name, Product Name
Events: value, quantity

I have created the following 2 tables (can change to matrix if need be):

Customer Table; showing the brands, products & quantity
Country Table; showing the brands, products & quantity

With the following slicers:
Customer slicer - on table 1 only
Country slicer - on both tables
Brand slicer - on both tables
So far it works well, but I'd like to add a distinct product count to both tables, which should adjust to the slicers.
Then easy comparison is possible on brand level to see if we list all products at customer 1 in country A vs what all retailers (1,2,3,+) have listed as product(s) in country A.
I tried
Distinct Count = DISTINCTCOUNT(Products[Product Name])
and
Distinct Count = CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT(Products[Product Name]), FILTER(Brands, Brands[Brand Name]) = MAX(Brands[Brand Name]))
but it still doesn't add up correctly!
